# Why does safari horizontally spill text on certain elements?

Tags: css, angularjs, safari, mobile-safari, translation

In Safari 7 on iOS and OSX I have certain elements in which the text is overflowing horizontally. These elements have their text populated by Angular Translate asynchronously. It looks as if Safari doesn't realize the content of the element changed isn't re-rendering it; Instead letting child elements overflow horizontally.

[image]

Comment: @Soviut, Could you craft a jsfiddle or at least share the CSS with us?

Comment: @Soviut  do you mean that the content is added programatically ??

Comment: Yes, the content is added at runtime by a translation directive in angular. It loads the translations from a language json file then propagates those translations to anywhere they're needed in the templates.

Comment: The issue seems to be some combination of inline block elements mixed with other display types.

Comment: please share example, for make us able to test it

Comment: @Soviut does this issue happen in ios safari only ? and please past e the element css.

Comment: @ProllyGeek yes, it's occurring in both iOS Safari 7 and OSX Safari 7.

Comment: no code, no way to test, nothing? Is people supposed to guess what your code is? You're a seasoned SO user, you should know better, this isn't the way to make a question at SO by ANY MEANS. I'm surprised it's still open, TBH. Also, no matter your bounty, any given answer should be a comment since you didn't provide any single bit of information, just an image which could be anything, thus it's impossible to provide nothing but a guess, hence a comment

Comment: @Fabio I've actually been struggling to isolate the issue in a fiddle without success. I was hoping there was a slim chance others had run into the issue and might recognize it.

Comment: Disable any and all CSS3 transforms applied to any of the parent elements in your chain and test again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a repaint/redraw issue that's been known to happen with Safari layout.

You can attempt to fix this with a couple lines of JavaScript that you'd want to fire off as soon as the content is loaded:

```
var sel = document.querySelector('#myElement') 
sel.style.display = 'run-in'; 
setTimeout(function () { sel.style.display = 'block'; }, 0);
```

That should redraw the box to the bounds of its contents.

Replace `'#myElement'` with the ID or class CSS selector to get your button.  The run-in (as opposed to 'none') setting prevents the element from flickering.  The zero-ms timeout setting the display back to block is what actually causes the repaint to occur.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm already doing this trick using a directive in angular. It's pretty ugly though.

Comment: With a fiddle I could solve this.  It'd be a huge help.

Comment: Here, I started with a real simple mockup here: http://jsfiddle.net/pq2asbhw/.  If you could make whatever changes are triggering this to happen in Safari I'll be happy to give it another look.

Comment: Not the outcome I was hoping for since this was my existing hack solution but I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in isolation in JSFiddle. Hopefully this just disappears in Safari 8.